# JSP Y MYSQL Mensaje desea borrar?

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jsp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A ver si me explico esta es la parte de borrar de mi tabla de la base de datos en jsp con MySQL

ahora el botón lo que hace es borrar pero quiero hacer que envié un mensaje a la hora de borrar estaba pensando en un if pero no se muy bien como aplicarlo si me pudieran ayudar por favor les agradecería :)

Comment: puedes manejarlo desde javascript, antes de enviar la petición al servidor mostra un mensaje de "confirmar". Si el cliente confirma que desea borrar, recién ahí enviar una request http con el ID de la persona a borrar

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de pedirle la confirmación al usuario es mediante el método `confirm()` en **Javascript**.

Utiliza `var confirmacion = confirm("¿Seguro que quieres borrar?");`

El método confirm devuelve un boolean. He encontrado un ejemplo en [esta](https://www.anerbarrena.com/javascript-confirm-js-5508/) página.